# Basic function logic

Tags: powershell

I am defining a function to switch from Player "X" to player "O". When I run this little block of code *without* the function, it gives me back an X. When I run this with a function defined it returns as O. What makes the difference between running it normally and running it from a Function ?

```
$playgame = "True"
$player = "O"

#Function
Switch-play
Write-host $player



#Switch Player turn
Function Switch-Play{
    if ($playgame = "True") {
        if ($player -eq "X") {$player = "O"}
        else {$player = "X"}
        }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: At first I was in doubt about defining the variables as $script:player, but that didn't really solve anything.

EDIT: changing to Switch-Play rather than Switch-play

```
PS C:\Users\scout> $playgame = "True"
$player = "O"
$player
Switch-Play
$player
Switch-Play 
$player




#Switch Player turn
Function Switch-Play{
    if ($playgame = "True") {
        if ($player -eq "X") {$player = "O"}
        else {$player = "X"}
        }
}
O
O
O
```

Comment: @jonhopkins Powershell is case-unsensitive...

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I included it in the Edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable Scope issue here. Change function like this:

```
Function Switch-Play{
    if ($playgame) {
        if ($global:player -eq "X") 
            {
              $global:player = "O"}
        else 
            {                
              $global:player = "X"
            }
        }
}
```

Reading about scope: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx

Comment: So in order to modify a variable outside a function with a function I would have to add $global: to that variable every time?

Comment: A variable is created in a scope(global=session, script for scripts, function ...). A child(ex. function) can READ a variable from it's parent(ex. script), but if you try to set the variable in the function, you are actually creating a new variable since your in a different scope(function). inheritance only works one way, down. To modify a variable in a parent scope, you must use the scope-modifier ex `$script:variablename`. Be aware that if you create a variable in a function with the same name as a var. in the parent scope, you need to use scope-modifier to READ too.

Comment: @SiemHermans. Yes, you need to declare the scope where you want the variable change is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could return the value of player from the function:

```
Function Switch-Play
{
    param
    ( 
      $playgame,
      $player
    )
    if ($playgame -eq $true) 
    { 
        if ($player -eq "X") 
        {
            $player = "O"
        }
        else 
        {
            $player = "X"
        }
        $player
    }
}

$player = "O"
$player = Switch-play -playgame $true -player $player
Write-host $player
```